# Remap Fn key to Insert key on Apple aluminium keyboard

Tags: keyboard, apple

How to hack Apple keybaord model A1243 (aluminium keyboard) to have <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on <kbd>Fn</kbd> button?

I've updated system to Kubuntu 13.10 and my keyboard stop working as usual. I've read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard and [Function keys in Apple Keyboard don't work as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33514/function-keys-in-apple-keyboard-dont-work-as-expected), tried `echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` without success.

I don't want to remap <kbd>F13</kbd> to <kbd>Insert</kbd>, or use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as <kbd>Insert</kbd>. On my last system (12.04 or earlier) <kbd>Fn</kbd> as <kbd>Insert</kbd> was working, but I cannot remember how I've hack it...

`xev` doesn't even report <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: **you can't remap <kbd>Fn</kbd> key**.

The long answer...

The purpose of <kbd>Fn</kbd> (short for *function*) key  is quite different: for example to change display or audio settings quickly, such as brightness, contrast, or volume, and is held down in conjunction with the appropriate key to change the settings. When you press only the the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, this doesn't send any data to the computer and for this reason `xev` can't detect it.

According with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/80961/147044), in general there is no way to know that <kbd>Fn</kbd> was pressed and the keycode of key-combinations including **<kbd>Fn</kbd> depends on the individual keyboard design**.

So unfortunately, you can't remap it to another key.

More about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key.