# How to swap Fn and Ctrl keys on a Dell?

Tags: keyboard-layout, ubuntu-studio, compaq

I have a Compaq Presario CQ50, running Ubuntu Studio 14.04. I would like to swap the Control and Function keys.

Lenovo ThinkPads allow this in their BIOS, there is also an option within the Ubuntu Studio 14.04 preferences on the ThinkPad. MacBooks are the same as ThinkPads. I want to setup the Compaq in the same manner. I like the function key to be at the far left.

If I have to remap the keyboard on the Compaq to be able to swap the Control and Function keys, then I would like to know how to make a custom keyboard layout. The only option I can find in the keyboard's preferences is to set the keyboard to the many different default languages.

If I have to install some keyboard modification application from the repositories, then what is its name so I can install it and modify my keyboard layout?

To be clear. I would like to make the leftmost key that is currently Control and swap it with Function, making the Control key become the Function key.

Comment: Doesn't look off-topic to me: I'm pretty sure there's a software (Ubuntu) way of doing this

Comment: @kos Any method to find the keycode for **Fn Key**? Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/80961/438174)

Comment: @araghuteja Hmmm thinking about this again this might be off-topic. It looks like the the scancodes for Fn combos are generated by the keyboard, hence this might be strictly hardware-dependant. Hitting Fn in `xev` outputs nothing.

Comment: Absolutely, check this one too--> [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/270428/438174)

Comment: We can find the keycode for **Fn+FuntionKey** pressed together. Fn key doesn't work alone, it works with secondary key to generate a unique code.  We can then bind **Ctrl+FunctionKey** to that keycode. But I don't think we can assign Fn to Ctrl...

Comment: Ubuntu Studio is an official derivative as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Ubuntu Studio is on-topic here**